# How can I correctly declare and access a container data member in a C++ class?

Tags: c++, stl

I have several classes with data members that are containers: std::vector and std::map. I've found in several cases that I get garbage data when accessing these containers. I'm starting to think that there must be a correct way to declare, pass, and access classes with containers as data members. However, all of my searches for containers and classes return how-to for container classes, which is not what I'm dealing with.

My class States represents the state of a quadrotor. I'm using OpenCV and my data members look like:

```
cv::Point3d X,V,b;
std::vector<Feature> features;
```

where Feature is another class describing a landmark in the environment.

Initially, I was passing class instances by reference:

```
foo( State& s );
```

The result was garbage when iterating over the vector.

I was able to resolve this issue by passing a pointer instead:

```
foo( State *s);
```

I'm a little surprised that using a pointer fixed my problem, but at least I have a solution.

Now I'm running into a second problem where I have overloaded operator+ and operator+= and this is causing similar unexpected behavior. I'll post the code for these methods below:
The + operator is defined outside of the States class:

```
inline States operator+(States lhs, const States& rhs)
{
    lhs+=rhs;
    return lhs;
}
```

The following methods are defined inside the States class:

```
    States&
States::operator+= ( const States& rhs )
{
    this->add(&rhs);
    return *this;
}

void States::add(const States& a)
{
    X += a->X;
    V += a->V;
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++ )
    {
        features[i].position.body += a->features[i].position.body;
        features[i].position.world += a->features[i].position.world;
    }
    b += a->b;
}
```

The question is, are there any obvious errors in my operator+,+=,add() and moreover is there some problem with the way I define and access my container members?

EDIT: Provide class definitions and operator and constructor definitions.
States.h:

```
class States{

public:
    Vec3d X;
    Vec3d V;
    Vec3d b;
    std::vector<Feature> features;
    std::map<int,Feature> feats;

    // constructor
    States();
    ~States();
    States(Vec3d pos, Vec3d vel, std::vector<Feature> feat, Vec3d bias, int n);
    States(cv::Mat kx);

    // accessor
    Vec3d getX();
    Vec3d getV();
    std::vector<Feature> getFeatures();
    Feature getFeature(int i);
    Vec3d getb();
    int getRows();
    int getNumFeatures();

    // mutator
    void update_features( ImageSensor *imgsense, Sensors sense );
    void end_loop (  );
    void setX(Vec3d pos);
    void setV(Vec3d vel);
    void setFeature(int i, Feature f);
    void addFeature(Feature f);
    void setb(Vec3d bias);
    void add(States a);
    States dynamics( Sensors s );
    //Operator
    States& operator*= ( const double& rhs );
    States& operator+= ( const States& rhs );
private:
};
inline States operator*(States lhs, const double& rhs)
{
    lhs*=rhs;
    return lhs;
}

inline States operator+(States lhs, const States& rhs)
{
    lhs+=rhs;
    return lhs;
}
```

States.cpp (operators and constructors): add() is a little diff here because it's from a later revision, but the problem is the same.

```
    States&
States::operator+= ( const States& rhs )
{
    this->add(rhs);
    return *this;
}

States::States ( cv::Mat kx )
{
    int nf;
    nf = (kx.rows-9)/3;
    setX( cv::Vec3d( kx.at<double>(0,0), kx.at<double>(1,0), kx.at<double>(2,0)) );
    setV( cv::Vec3d( kx.at<double>(3,0), kx.at<double>(4,0), kx.at<double>(5,0)) );
    for( int i=0; i<nf; ++i )
    {
        Feature ft( cv::Vec3d( kx.at<double>(9+3*i,0), kx.at<double>(10+3*i,0),  kx.at<double>(11+3*i,0) ),
                cv::Scalar(0,0,0), 0 );
            addFeature(ft);
    }
    setb( cv::Vec3d( kx.at<double>(6,0), kx.at<double>(7,0), kx.at<double>(8,0) ) );
    return ;
}       /* -----  end of method States::States  ----- */


States::States(Vec3d pos, Vec3d vel, std::vector<Feature> feat, Vec3d bias, int n)
{
    X = pos;
    V = vel;
    features = feat;
    b = bias;
}

void States::add(States a)
{
    if( a.getNumFeatures()!=getNumFeatures() )
    {
        std::cerr << "add: feature mismatch" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    X += a.X;
    V += a.V;
    for(int i = 0; i<getNumFeatures(); i++ )
    {
        features[i].position.body += a.features[i].position.body;
        features[i].position.world += a.features[i].position.world;
    }
    b += a.b;
}
```

Comment: I refuse to believe that using a pointer instead of a reference truly fixed your problem.

Comment: @Quentin No, it is passed by value on purpose. If you pass it by reference, then you still need to make a local copy inside `operator+()` before performing `+=`.

Comment: There is no problem using `foo( State& s );`, if you post a minified working example, would be better to get a response.

Comment: And yeah, I'd rather fix your issue with the reference first. That might fix this problem. I'd suggest closing this question, going back to the reference problem, formulating a working example, and then posting a new question about that.

Comment: @JosephMansfield ouch, end of the week is visible...

Comment: @user40808 did you verify that the data is correctly inserted into the vectors?

Comment: @JosephMansfield I'll reproduce the reference problem in a simplified function.

Comment: @chris If you don't believe that it corrected my output, I verified it against known good outputs. If you are suggesting that there is some larger, unresolved, problem, I agree, which is why I described that problem in my question.

Comment: Can we see the full definition of your `State` class, or at the very least constructors, destructor, and operators?

Comment: @MarkB Added the header file, constructors, and operators.

Comment: Run this through Valgrind with your reference implementation. I suspect it will be rather telling. (related: the amount of unneeded copying in some of your members is a little daunting, btw).

Comment: @WhozCraig good idea on valgrind, I'm using it now. Can I ask what copying you find daunting?

Comment: @presocratics The constructor for `States` taking three `Vec3d` objects and a `std::vector<Feature>`, *all* by value-copy would be a good example. And *all* of the members assigned in the constructor body should be in an initializer list. As I recall, some things OpenCV self-reference counts, but that should not stop stuff like this from being cleaned up.